# Ip or iam user from which Publish message request made to sns topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a lambda function that is invoking around 60million times from one sns topic, in the sns topic metrics i could see it is publish around 600k msgs but I wanted to know how we can check which iam user has made the publish message request in that topic and how can we get the IP from which message are published?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know there is no way you can monitor what you are asking for. What you can do is to search `ClouTrail` logs and figure out yourself which user made how many requests to sns. There is also a way to put the logs(`CloudTrail`) in `CloudWatch` but it's not cheap process. If you are interested, you check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/analyzing-cloudtrail-in-cloudwatch/).

Comment: There is no trail event for publish message

Comment: @UmangAggarwal, your question is not clear. Can you explain a bit better? When a message is published, it invokes a lambda or vice versa? If lambda invokes sns messages, who invokes lambda?